# Select Dataframe Columns based on Number of Nulls in Each

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have seen similar questions but what I am facing is slightly different. I am trying to select a subset of the columns in my dataframe, based on whether the columns have less than 300 nulls.

```
df[df.columns[df.isnull().any()]].isnull().sum()<300
```

I have succeeded at creating this boolean array, but how would I pass this info back to select only df columns where this is True?

Comment: You can only accept a single answer... just fyi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us using `thresh` from the doc *Require that many non-NA values.*

```
df.dropna(axis = 1,thresh = len(df)-300)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `any` is redundant, you can do this with just `isnull`/`isna` and `sum`:

```
v = df.isna().sum().lt(300)
df[v.index[v]]
```

Or,

```
df.loc[:, df.isna().sum().lt(300)]
```